# Google Search console showing "other error" while indexing page

Tags: sitemap, google-crawlers

I have created my website. I have submitted sitemap for Crowle on my website. But most of the pages Google is not able to index. I have reviewed the indexing report Tested Page Report >> More Info tab. I found that Google showing the other errors.

Here is the list of URLs

Other error
http://www.xyzabc.com/?gdsih-csp-report

 Other error
Script
http://www.xyzabc.com/wp-content/plugins/gpt3-ai-content-generator/public/js/wpaicg-chat.js

    Other error
Script
http://www.xyzabc.com/wp-content/plugins/gpt3-ai-content-generator/public/js/wpaicg-init.js

Here is the script tag

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.xyzabc.com/wp-content/plugins/gpt3-ai-content-generator/public/js/wpaicg-init.js" id="wpaicg-init-js"></script>
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.